# How do I cause re-rendering to the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I cause re-rendering to the component

```
function Bookmarks({ data }: any) {
  const bookmarkedBlogs = useBookmarks().getBookmarkedBlogs(data.allMdx.nodes);
   .....
}
```

when bookmarks change in the hook

```
function useBookmarks() {
  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks, accessDenied] = useLocalStorage<BlogType['id'][]>('bookmarks', []);

  const getBookmarkedBlogs = (blogs: BlogType[]) => {
    return blogs.filter(checkIsBookmarked)
  };
```

because as of now, even if I toggle bookmarks, the getBookmarkedBlogs function doesn't execute except in the initial render of the component.

Comment: You should use `:key="refresh"` in the component template and then simply increment the `refresh` variable to trigger a re-render. Or use a boolean variable and simply toggle it between `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 0):

How the implementation of `useLocalStorage`, and how you toggle bookmarks?

- localStorage changes don't notify your every hooks except your make a observer model
- if you don't make observer model, toggle bookmark in other hooks or other ways wouldn't notify your this hook, so it don't rerun

Answer (score 0):

Your hook doesn't actually work.

It seems like you want a hook that subscribes to updates from some source outside the React render tree.

Here's a simple example of something that works like that:

```js
function MyComp() {
  let eventValue = useEventListener()
  
  return (
    <div>
      {eventValue}
    </div>
  )
}


function useEventListener() {
  let [ value, setValue ] = React.useState(1)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setValue(5), 1000)
  }, [])
  
  return value
}
```

What makes it work is that the custom hook invokes a built-in hook when data should change. The React Hooks framework handles the rest.

Instead of a `setTimeout`, you could subscribe to an event stream, or listen for IPC messages, or something else. But:

1. The custom hook has to actually return something
2. The custom hook can only trigger a re-render by invoking a builtin hook
3. The custom hook must set up its subscribe-to-changes logic on its first invocation, which is often best handled by `useEffect` configured to run once